# how to give size of a control in window mobile app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

how to give size of a  control in window mobile app dynamically,because i have developed one application,when i used to run that application on different emulator's ,the size of that control's in that application differ's for different emulator.so could u plz help me that how we can handle such issue in windows mobile application in which iam using visual studio 2008 and windows mobile6 classical emulator

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, but I'll take a stab at it.

Apparent control size (how big it looks to your eye) if affected byt a few things.  The obvious are things like Dock and Achor properties, which are well documented online and are the same as for the desktop.  What is less obvious is scaling.  Some PDAs have a 240x320 display, while others may have 480x640 yet with the same physical dimension screen.

The platform can attempt to have your single Form code work for both by doing "[pixel doubling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb431747.aspx)" which essentially just doubles all of your size values.  This tends to end up with graininess and I think it was turned off by default starting with WinMo 6.

To adjust this behavior, you can [adjust your Form's AutoScaleMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx).